# Android Studio (API 23) - I want to reuse a fragment across multiple activities, but with a unique layout in each activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Is this possible?

Essentially -

I want ActivityA to host FragmentA with layoutA, and I want ActivityB to host FragmentA with layoutB.  I can't seem to figure out a way to do it conveniently.

Thank you!

Sorry - I don't have any example code handy that's worth looking at!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a point for 2 layouts in same fragment file because binding the views and handle it will be big .. yes you can render different layouts depending on any flag you pass to fragment like this

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val flag = requireArguments().getInt("AnyCustomFlag", 0)
    return if (flag == 1)
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_a, container, false)
    else
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_b, container, false)
}
```

Comment: How would you approach this situation?  I just got dropped into this application, and the main activity fragment is massive and communicates with a ton of hardware, so I figured having two activities with the same functionality would be redundant.  Sorry - I'm new to Android!

Comment: It is OK you should search for Send parameters to fragments and when you know it you will be able to decide the flag that needs to inflate the layouts you want

Answer (score 0):

You can check the activity class inside the onCreateView and assign the good layout

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(getActivity() instanceof  ActivityA ? R.layout.fragment_a : R.layout.fragment_b, container, false); ;
    }
```